# Pulling back the "test-element"? (Orthogonal factorization systems)

Tags: category-theory

Below is the statement and proof of Lemma 3.1 from the paper [*Reflective subcategories, localizations, and factorization systems*](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_38_03%2FS1446788700023624a.pdf&code=99c752c70c86fb397005a5003ed21b36) by Cassidy Hébert and Kelly.

**Lemma 3.1.** Let $\mathcal N$ be a class of monomorphisms in $\mathsf C$, closed under composition; let $\mathsf C$ admit all pulbacks (along any map) of maps in $\mathcal N$, and all intersections of maps in $\mathcal N$; and let these pullbacks and intersections again belong to $\mathcal N$. Then $(\mathcal N^\perp,\mathcal N)$ is a strong factorization system.

**Proof.** $f:A\to B$ factors as $me$, where $m$ is the intersection of the $\mathcal N$-subobjects of $B$ through which $f$ factors; it is easy to see that $e\in \mathcal N^\perp$, by pulling back the "**test-element**" of $\mathcal N$.

What is meant by "**test-element**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $e : A \to f(A) \in \mathcal{N}^\bot$, you have to pick arbitrary $m \in \mathcal{N}$ and show that if
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{e}>> f(A)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
C @>{m}>> D
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, then there exists a diagonal $f(A) \to C$. Presumably, the "test element" refers to $m$, because the proof goes as follows: take the pullback of $f(A) \to D \leftarrow C$; then, since $e$ factorizes through this pullback, the projection onto $f(A)$ must be an isomorphism. Inverting this isomorphism and composing it with the projection onto $C$ gives the desired morphism $f(A) \to C$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you perhaps take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882699/reflective-factorization-systems-from-reflections-to-general-adjunction) as well?

Comment: I looked at it, but delving into an article would take more time than I have to spare right now.